# When using Mindstorms Scratch-like development tool for EV3, is it possible to move a single or a few selected blocks somehow?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming, scratch

Say I have 10 random blocks in a line.
Is it possible to move number 4 to position 1 without also moving block 5-10?
As far as I have managed to move blocks all following blocks also gets moved even if I just want to move a single block.

Moving blocks seem really hard in Mindstorms software when working with loops and if blocks, at least when you want to decide the actual target position.

Answer (score 2):

You have to break the blocks apart in two places so the one(s) you want to move are not attached to anything else. Then move the separated block(s) to where you want them. And finally put everything back together again.

[image: screen capture of steps in action]

<sub>Note: the screen shot is from the SPIKE programming software, not EV3 - in case you don't recognize some of the blocks.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That’s sad. Then it’s worse than the EV3 Labview block programming. I guess I’ll have to change to EV3 python then.